# atoi function in C not working properly (when exceeding a certain value)

Tags: c, atoi

Might someone explain why the **atoi** function doesn't work for nmubers with more than 9 digits?

For example:

When I enter: `123456789`,
The program program returns: `123456789`,

However,when I enter: `12345678901`
the program returns: `-519403114...`

```
int main ()
{
    int i;
    char szinput [256];
    printf ("Enter a Card Number:");
    fgets(szinput,256,stdin);
    i=atoi(szinput);
    printf("%d\n",i);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: atoi is for integer. When you need larger integers than MAXINT, use atol.

Comment: `atoi` is for `int`, not "integer".  Both `int` and `long` are integer types.

Comment: On most systems, `int` and `long` are the same size, so you'll probably want a function that works with larger types..

Comment: @R.. At least for Mac OS and iOS, int is always 32 bits for bot 32 and 64 bit system. long is 32 bits for 32, 64 bits for 64.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `atoi()`, or any of the `atoi*()` functions, if you care about error handling.  These functions provide no way of detecting errors; neither `atoi(99999999999999999999)` nor `atoi("foo")` has any way to tell you that there was a problem.  (I think that one or both of those cases actually has undefined behavior, but I'd have to check to be sure.)

The `strto*()` functions are a little tricky to use, but they can reliably tell you whether a string represents a valid number, whether it's in range, and what its value is.  (You have to deal with `errno` to get full checking.)

If you just want an int value, you can use `strtol()` (which, after error checking, gives you a `long` result) and convert it to `int` after *also* checking that the result is in the representable range of `int` (see `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` in `<limits.h>`).  `strtoul()` gives you an `unsigned long` result.  `strtoll()` and `strtoull`() are for `long long` and `unsigned long long` respectively; they're new in C99, and your <strike>compiler</strike> implementation might not support them (though most non-Microsoft implementations probably do).

Answer (score 7):

Because you are overflowing an `int` with such a large value.

Moreover, `atoi` is deprecated and thread-unsafe on many platforms, so you'd better ditch it in favour of `strto(l|ll|ul|ull)`.

Consider using [`strtoull`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoull) instead. Since `unsigned long long` is a 64-bit type on most modern platforms, you'll be able to convert a number as big as `2 ^ 64` (`18446744073709551616`).

To print an `unsigned long long`, use the `%llu` format specifier.

Comment: `strtoull()` won't handle negative numbers, and might not be available on all implementations.  `strtol()` is ok for int values.

Answer (score 0):

if you are writing **win32** application then you can use windows implementation of atoi, for details check the below page.

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czcad93k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx